# How to specify less options to angular-cli

Tags: angular, less, angular-cli

I would like to use the options `strictMath` with less, when using angular-cli, but I don't know how to do this.

I'm using the current last version of angular-cli:

> angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.19-3
>
> node: 6.9.1
>
> os: win32 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what do you want to do, specify less or more options?

:D Jokes aside, up until now almost no additional configuration can be specified.

What you can do, is access the `angular-cli` folder inside `node_modules` and modify LESS compiler configuration there.

Keep in mind, that after updating the `angular-cli` you will have to reapply your changes.

The angular-cli team plans to make more configuration accessible in a future version (post final version).

Comment: I was scared of that...
Any idea of where I should go exactly in the node_modules?

Comment: There should be an angular-cli folder inside. Unfortunately I don't know the less compiler so I don't know what the configuration looks like, have a look around

Comment: That's pretty sad state of affairs to be honest

Comment: this is a very old post... but can it be done now, in 2023?